# Optimizing GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, jvm

I'm beginner in geomatics, and I have created a web mapping. I use GeoServer as server of data WMS. My layers is stocked in PostgreSQL and  I have optimised this and the styles. Now I want optimize GeoServer because the map display is slow. I would like to display the Heap Jump in JVM console in server status but there is error.  Just saw a error of the display of Heap Jump in JVM Console of the GeoServer.  Any suggestions?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/558ve.png]

Answer (score 2):

A heap dump is useful to analyze an Out Of Memory issue, not a performance one.

Have a look at some optimization tricks here:
https://www.slideshare.net/geosolutions/geoserver-in-production-we-do-it-here-is-how-foss4g-2016

In general, if it's slow and you already tuned the data and style, either the CPUs are underpowered or you're drawing too many features. You can check out cached tiles with WMTS as a way to get instant responses in exchange for less flexibility.

Comment: Ok but how can i display this for control the memorie issue?

Comment: You need to run GeoSever against a JDK in order to have the jmap tool available on the command line, you are likely running against a JRE Instead.